# Would like to get running total of comission SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

i'm trying to acheive the following result from one table, "policies"

```
+-------------+------------------+
|Commission   |Total Commission  |
+-------------+------------------+
|108          |108               |
+-------------+------------------+
|50           |158               |
+-------------+------------------+
|12           |170               |
+-------------+------------------+

and so on...
```

so far, my query looks like this:

```
SELECT
  P.commission
  SUM(P.commission) OVER (PARTITION BY P.id ORDER BY P.id) AS "Total Commission"
FROM
  policies P
```

except use of `OVER` doesn't seem to be working (words such as `SELECT`, `SUM()` and `FROM` all change text colour to blue because they're keywords)

Please could someone suggest a way to get this working how I want it

```
EDIT:: p.policy_id didn't exist. Was just p.id, corrected.
EDIT2:: incorrect spelling of "commission", corrected
```

Further edit:

I am now using the following query, which is fetching the following result:

```
SELECT p.commission,
   (SELECT SUM(p2.commission)
    FROM policies p2
    WHERE p2.id = p.id AND p2.id <= p.id
   ) AS total_commission
FROM policies p;


+-------------+------------------+
|Commission   |Total Commission  |
+-------------+------------------+
|108          |108               |
+-------------+------------------+
|50           |50                |
+-------------+------------------+
|12           |12                |
+-------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Tag your question with the *database* you are using.

Comment: Your where clause should be `WHERE p2.id <= p.id`, not `WHERE p2.id = p.id AND p2.id <= p.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using MySQL, which doesn't support window functions.

You can use a correlated subquery instead:

```
SELECT p.comission,
       (SELECT SUM(p2.comission)
        FROM policies p2
        WHERE p2.id = p.id and p2.policy_id <= p.policy_id
       ) as total_comission
FROM policies p;
```

Comment: This gave me a 1054 "Unknown column 'p.commission' in 'field list'

Comment: My mistake, spelling error was in question. Corrected question.

Comment: policy_id doesn't exist, that was also an error. but i've now corrected the question. should have been p2.id.

Comment: `partition by p.id order by p.id` doesn't make sense.  You need a stable sort if you want to calculate cumulative sums.  (I mean, you don't *need* to have a stable sort, but I prefer queries that make sense.)

Comment: Probably right. And I removed it! guess what? Query works now! thanks!